# Argument Error with ruby socket programming

Tags: ruby, sockets, websocket

I am trying to connect to a server and send a simple hello message.

My socket is properly connecting to to the server as i get a connection establish acknowledgment from the server side. but when i am trying to send data to the server using the `send` method it gives me an error saying 
`Argument Error : Wrong number of arguments, (given 1, expected 2...3).`
The tutorial that i have followed to get it working had just one argument with send method, and even after looking for a while i cant find what other arguments needs to be passed

Here is my code: 
Client.rb

```
require 'socket'
host = host_name
port = port_number 
streamSock = TCPSocket::new( host, port )
streamSock.send( "Hello\n" )
str = streamSock.recv( 1024 )
print str
streamSock.close
```

The `print str` prints the server message but the send methods throws an error.

Comment: Which line of the code is your error pointing to?

Comment: line number 5 @SaraTibbetts, line number 6,7 and 8 executes properly

Comment: I know little about ruby, per se, but every version of the documentation I see shows `TCPSocket`'s `send` being inherited from `BasicSocket` and requiring at least two arguments: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/socket/rdoc/BasicSocket.html#send-method. Try adding a second `flags` argument of zero.